# X11 Programming on Raspberry Pi

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, x11

I'm wanting to develop a GUI application for the Raspberry Pi. I want this application to run without the overhead of a Desktop GUI environment, directly on X11. My google searching has led me nowhere trying to find examples of people doing this. My preferred platform is Qt, although if an option were available in another language/environment I would be open to it. My question is: does anyone know of examples of applications that do this? I'm just looking for anything to get me started.

Comment: Qt works without X11 on a RPi2 (not sure about the 1, to be honest), allowing you to open one fullscreen window via its EGLFS display plugin. If you cross compile Qt accordingly then ***any*** example shipped with Qt will do this.

Comment: I agree with peppe, you don't need nor want X11 on RPi just to run a Qt application. It will work much better without the overhead of X11.